# Firestore PHP SDK - How to save date?

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I try save date in firestore but every time was saved like string or number, I need save as timestamp

```
date( 'U', strtotime( '-4 HOUR' ) ); // result something like 1605958160
```

Example of PHP

```
$docRef = $db->collection('users')->document('lovelace');
$docRef->set([
    'first' => 'Ada',
    'last' => 'Lovelace',
    'born' => date( 'U', strtotime( '-4 HOUR' ) )
]);
```

Comment: How is the `born` column defined in the schema

Comment: I no have schema, where I need create schema? I just follow this article https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model

Answer (score 3):

Follow information give from [@RiggsFolly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64945043/firestore-php-sdk-how-to-save-date?noredirect=1#comment114820304_64945043) I found this information of Github Google Cloud Platform [How to add timestamp to firestore](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/blob/41135fbba5caec7d89b95fbbcebcc65dc8eb03d3/firestore/src/add_doc_data_types.php#L45-L56)

Just use

```
new DateTime('2000-01-01', new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo'));
```

Thanks